# How can I correct the path of a file to be OS specific in Perl?

Tags: perl, filenames, portability

Due to some messed up legacy code,

I have

```
$path = [OS specific base DIR name][hardcoded Linux file path]
```

So on Linux, it is something like

```
$path = /common/path/to/dir/pathtofile/name.extension
```

but on Windows it becomes this

```
$path = C:\path\to\dir\pathtofile/name.extension
```

Some of the code fails on Windows because it is expecting a `\` while it gets a `/`.

**Is there a Perl function that can help me here?**

Something like

```
print "$path\n";
$path = <some function> $path;
print "$path\n";

C:\path\to\dir\pathtofile/name.extension
C:\path\to\dir\pathtofile\name.extension
```

Comment: Windows doesn't mind slashes instead of backslashes - not in the API.  So, are you providing the filename to a `cmd.exe` process (because that does get stroppy about / introducing command options)?

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks, I should have replied earlier. After I posted the question, I figured out that the forward slash was not the actual problem (as you correctly mentioned here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) family of modules exists exactly for that reason. You might want to consider using that instead of hardcoding unix paths.

```
use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

my $path = catfile($os_specific_base_dir, 'pathtofile', 'name.extension');
```

If you really need to hardcode unix paths somewhere, which really doesn't seem like a good idea, you should probably use `File::Spec::Unix` to split up the path into its components, and then use the `File::Spec` variant native to your target system to build put the components back together again.

Comment: yes, I know about catfile and how it can be used to generate OS specific names. I have used that before. In this case, I have no control over the names that I get. I get `$path` set from somewhere already. I can only change it after I get it (as I have mentioned in the question).

Comment: Right. That's why I mentioned an alternative for handling that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) core modules - and related ones?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting the entire $path handed to you from somewhere else as one unit, rather than having the luxury of dealing with the pieces separately.  In which case, I don't see a better answer than the ugly solution of replacing all slashes with backslashes if we're running under Windows.

The following should do what you need:

```
if ($^O =~ /^MSWin/) {
    $path =~ s{/}{\\}g;
}
```

**EDIT**: On second thought -- having taken a look at File::Spec, it looks like you want the `canonpath` function:

```
use File::Spec;
# ...
$path = File::Spec->canonpath($path);
```